# How many bits are in NON 10bit video?

Tags: video

Recently saw an information about so called 10-bit video or Hi10P.

Unfortunately, I didn't understand, if this more than normal or less than normal.

I can't think that it is more than normal because can't think that normal video is 8 bit (256 colors) or 9 bit (512 colors).

Ho many "bits" are in non-10 bit, i.e. "normal" video?

Comment: What makes you think its more then 10 bits? "NON 10bit" isn't a thing by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal graphics has 8 bits per channel, that is 2<sup>8</sup> bits which equals 256. There are three channels: red, green, and blue, so 256<sup>3</sup> = 16,777,216 colors. This is all that Windows can display. A 10 bit monitor can display 2<sup>10</sup> shades per channel for a total of 1,073,741,824 colors. I do not know if there are any operating systems that can actually display that many colors, but a quick cursory Google search seems to indicate it's coming to Apple.
(My answer assumes you're referring to video as it applies to computing.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/20776/h-264-high-profile-codec-video.html) article, color depth can typically range from 8 to 12 bit in h.264 - with 8 bit color being pretty standard.

[This](http://leavcom.com/2014f/imgtec_f040014.php) article (when talking about Bt.2020 - for Blu Ray and 4k) explains that the bit depth is PER color - so for each of Red, Green and Blue.  Thus 8 bit depth is already quite a bit, not the 256 colors we would have expected.